# Open submit in new tab (or window) and replace the content of this tab in a for loop

Tags: javascript, xhtml

The following HTML document contains a form which should be submitted by the script. The value of the text field is set initially to 50000 and the form is submitted in a new window and the script STOPS but that's not what I want; I want the script to open the new window for 50000 then do the same for 50001, 50002, ...,55000, of course in the same opened window

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function now(){
for (i=50000;i<=55000;i++){
document.getElementById("candidate_id").value=i;
document.forms["here"].submit();
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="now()">
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://www.naharnet.com/examresults" method="post" target="_blank" id="here" name="here">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ksuw0r4TRM80q1Sw+dBoYRSrw7tfxmjLpVIVyqJnnhs=" /></div>
            <div class="row">
              <h5 id="category">Exam Category</h5>
                <select id="exam_category" name="exam_category">
              <option value="SG">SG </option>
              <option value="SV"> SV </option>
              <option value="SE">SE</option>
              <option value="LH">LH</option>
              <option value="BR">BR</option></select>
            </div>

             <div id="padding">
                <h5 id="cand_num">Candidate #</h5>
                <input id="candidate_id" maxlength="5" name="candidate_id" type="text"/>
             </div>


          <div id="padding">

            <input class="search_btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Search"/>

         </div>


</form> 

</body></html>
```

Comment: You can't submit more than once, because submitting relinquishes control to the new URL. You might be able to do something with AJAX calls...

Comment: @MrLister I a newbie to javascript and XML and I still don't know anything about AJAX. I hope you can help me with this.